# PL/SQL Developer Initialization error

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I want use PL/SQL Developer

first my oracle directory

`C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN`

I use windows10 and environment variable setting

`ORACLE_HOME C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1`

`Path C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN`
but execute Initialization error.

```
Initialization error
Could not load "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll"

OracleHomeKey: SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient10g_home1
OracleHomeDir: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
Found: oci.dll
Using: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll
LoadLibrary(C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll) return 0
```

Comment: Maybe you are using the 64-bit version of PL/SQL developer and a 32-bit Oracle Client. If so, the fix would be to switch to either a 32-bit version of PL/SQL Developer or a 64-bit Oracle client.

Answer (score 19):

1. download oracle instant client (64 bits for latest version of PL/SQL; 32 bits for old version)
2. extract to a folder. for example: `c:\oracle\instantclient`
3. open PL/SQL developer--> Configure--> Preferences --> Oracle Connection
4. under OCI library, keyin `OCI.DLL` file path in the text box: `c:\oracle\instantclient\oci.dll`
5. click OK and restart PL/SQL

Comment: When you have multiple Oracle Home configured then even after this explicit setup, it is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same error on my new windows 10 computer. At last i found that i missed the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads#bookmark-vs2013). After i install it, the error gone.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting below error while connecting to database from PL/SQL developer (in windows10 64 bit).

> Initialization error
> Could not initialize
> "C:\app<username>\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll"

Make sure you have the 32 bits Oracle Client installed.

```
OracleHomeKey: 
OracleHomeDir: C:\app\<username>\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
Found: oci.dll
Using: C:\app\<username>\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll
LoadLibrary(C:\app\<username>\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll) 
return 0
```

To resolve this issue, refer to the below documentation provided by Oracle to install the Oracle Instant Client. If your windows is 64 bit, then download the 32 bit Oracle Instant Client from below link -

Oracle [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.html#GUID-8C502BDD-C1A1-4EA0-9E88-D2F8452D4AC2)

Link to download the [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html) - (Download the BASIC and SDK and SQL*Plus Package)

Take all the above three packages in one directory and extract the same and add the path of extracted directory in system environment variable PATH and *OCI_LIB32*.

If *OCI_LIB32* is not present then create the same.

Try to connect to database from PLSQL developer, if you getting error as *'ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress'* then go through the below [link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/tips/oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress/)

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Check Environment Variables %PATH%

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and these steps did helped me

steps:

- Download oracle instant client (64 bits for latest version of PL/SQL; 32 bits for old version)
- Extract to a folder. for example: c:\oracle\instantclient
- Open PL/SQL developer--> Configure-->Preferences--> Oracle Connection
- Under OCI library, keyin OCI.DLL file path in the text box: c:\oracle\instantclient\oci.dll
- Click OK and restart PL/SQL
  done

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases this happens

1. If you dont have any oracle client

*In this case, you can download instant client and put it in C drive, then copy the path of the oci.dll file path and put it in the OCI library text field in the PL SQL Dev config option*

2. If you have multiple oracle home

*If you have multiple homes reflecting, then check the correct oracle home from the Oracle Home drop down in PLSQL Dev config option.*

Attached the image of the config screen for easy reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download oracle client after that use PL/SQL to connect